# overlay interaction visual in python

Tags: python, plot, graph, data-visualization, visualization

I want to visualize the interactions between two data's. Original (green) and prediction (brown). The length of the top line is from 200 to -20 and bottom from  -20  to 200.

[image]

For the above table, I want to visualize in the below format

[image]

code I have tried so far

```
    def newline(p1, p2, color='black'):
      ax = plt.gca()

   fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(5,5), dpi= 60)
   ax.hlines(y=1, xmin=-20, xmax=200, color='black', alpha=0.7)
   ax.hlines(y=1.1, xmin=-20, xmax=200, color='black', alpha=0.7)


   plt.rcParams['xtick.bottom'] = plt.rcParams['xtick.labelbottom'] = True
   plt.rcParams['xtick.top'] = plt.rcParams['xtick.labeltop'] = True
   ax.yaxis.set_visible(False)
   plt.box(False)
```

Comment: Please show what you tried. This is no free coding service.

Comment: Start with some matplotlib examples

Comment: Please post an image of your code and explain your approach. What was your idea to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

def newline(p1, p2, color='black'):
ax = plt.gca()

df = pd.read_excel('visual.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet2')
prediction_list = df['prediction'].tolist()
originale_list = df['original'].tolist()
result_prediction = []
result_original = []

for i in range(len(prediction_list)):
temp = []
test = prediction_list[i].split('&')
for j in range(len(test)):
temp = []
temp.append(200 - int(test[j].split(':')[0]))
temp.append(int(test[j].split(':')[1]))
result_prediction.append(temp)

for i in range(len(originale_list)):
temp = []
test = originale_list[i].split('&')
for j in range(len(test)):
temp = []
temp.append(200 - int(test[j].split(':')[0]))
temp.append(int(test[j].split(':')[1]))
result_original.append(temp)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(20,5), dpi= 60)
ax.hlines(y=1, xmin=200, xmax=-20, color='black', alpha=0.7)
ax.hlines(y=2, xmin=200, xmax=-20, color='black', alpha=0.7)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     -20')

for i in range(len(result_prediction)):
plt.plot(result_prediction[i], [2, 1], color='brown')
for i in range(len(result_original)):
plt.plot(result_original[i], [2, 1], color='green')

plt.rcParams['xtick.bottom'] = plt.rcParams['xtick.labelbottom'] = True
plt.rcParams['xtick.top'] = plt.rcParams['xtick.labeltop'] = True
ax.yaxis.set_visible(False)
plt.box(False)

plt.savefig('test.png')
plt.show()
```

That will be help you.

Thanks

Comment: That will be help you.